# How to reuse export variables in Azure pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have created a azure-pipelines.yml , in this I have different scripts section which run based on condition , every script sections have variables define , I want to make a common section which can host variables for all scripts.
Below is yml file , looking for a solution which will remove duplicates.

```
variables:
- group: spCreds
- group: toolCreds

steps:
- checkout: git://stack-deployment
- checkout: self
- script: |
    set -x
    export USE_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL=true
    export APP_NAME=testing
    export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET=$(ARM_CLIENT_SECRET)
    export ARM_TENANT_ID=${ARM_TENANT_ID}
    export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=${ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID}
    export ARM_CLIENT_ID=${ARM_CLIENT_ID}
    export ARM_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME=${ARM_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME}
    export ARM_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME=${ARM_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}
    export ARM_CONTAINER_NAME=${ARM_CONTAINER_NAME}
    
    bash -x bt-ciaas-stack-deployment/scripts/deploy.sh
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop'))
  displayName: 'deploy jenkins from develop branch'

- script: |
    export APP_NAME=testing
    export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET=$(ARM_CLIENT_SECRET)
    export ARM_TENANT_ID=${ARM_TENANT_ID}
    export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=${ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID}
    export ARM_CLIENT_ID=${ARM_CLIENT_ID}
    export ARM_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME=${ARM_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME}
    export ARM_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME=${ARM_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}
    export ARM_CONTAINER_NAME=${ARM_CONTAINER_NAME}    
   
   bash -x stack-deployment/scripts/deploy.sh
  condition: and(succeeded(), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/pull/'))
  displayName: 'Deploy from pull request'

- script: |
    export APP_NAME=testing
    export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET=$(ARM_CLIENT_SECRET)
    export ARM_TENANT_ID=${ARM_TENANT_ID}
    export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=${ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID}
    export ARM_CLIENT_ID=${ARM_CLIENT_ID}
    export ARM_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME=${ARM_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME}
    export ARM_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME=${ARM_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}
    export ARM_CONTAINER_NAME=${ARM_CONTAINER_NAME}    
   
   bash -x stack-deployment/scripts/delete.sh
  condition: and(succeeded(), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/pull/'))
  displayName: 'Delete'
```

I want to remove all the duplicate export variables and keep them at one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to reuse export variables in Azure pipelines

We could try to export duplicate variables in one task with combination condition:

```
or(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop'), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/pull/'))
```

The test scripts like:

```
steps:
- checkout: git://stack-deployment
- checkout: self
- script: |
    set -x
    export USE_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL=true
    
    bash -x bt-ciaas-stack-deployment/scripts/deploy.sh
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop'))
  displayName: 'deploy jenkins from develop branch'


- script: |
    export APP_NAME=testing
    export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET=$(ARM_CLIENT_SECRET)
    export ARM_TENANT_ID=${ARM_TENANT_ID}
    export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=${ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID}
    export ARM_CLIENT_ID=${ARM_CLIENT_ID}
    export ARM_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME=${ARM_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME}
    export ARM_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME=${ARM_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}
    export ARM_CONTAINER_NAME=${ARM_CONTAINER_NAME}    
   
   bash -x stack-deployment/scripts/common.sh
  or(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop'), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/pull/'))
  displayName: 'common'
```